$\int_\mathcal{C} \frac{k}{k^2 +\sigma^2} \, J_0(k) H_0^{(1)}(k\rho)\,\mathrm{d}k$ with $\mathcal{C}$ representing a semicircle of radius $R\to\infty$
I would like to find the expression for the following integral over the contour of integration $\mathcal{C}$, representing a semicircle of radius $R$ with $\theta \in [0,\pi]$, in the limit $R \to \infty$. This is part of the calculation for an improper integral. Specifically,
$$
\int_\mathcal{C} \frac{k}{k^2 + \sigma^2} \, J_0(k) H_0^{(1)}(k\rho) \, \mathrm{d}k \, ,
$$
with $\sigma > 0$ and $\rho \in [0,1]$.
Here, $J_0$ and $H_0^{(1)}$ denote the zeroth-order Bessel function and Hankel function of the first kind, respectively.
Using the change of variable $k = R e^{i\theta}$ and expanding the result in a series around $R \to \infty$, I can obtain an approximate expression.
Is it possible to derive an exact result? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Who are $J_0$ and $H_0^{(1)}$?

@Nicolas $J_0$ and $H_0^{(1)}$ denote the zeroth-order Bessel function and Hankel function of the first kind, respectively.

Knowing $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^{2}+\sigma^{2}} , J_{0}(\rho k) H_{0}^{(1)}(k) , \mathrm dk = 2I_{0}(\rho \sigma) K_{0}(\sigma), \quad 0 \le \rho \le 1,  $$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^{2}+\sigma^{2}} ,  J_{0}(\rho k) H_{0}^{(1)}(k) , \mathrm dk = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^{2}+\sigma^{2}} , J_{0}(k) H_{0}^{(1)}(\rho k) , \mathrm dk,  $$ the integral in question must be going to $2  I_{0}(\sigma)K_{0}(\rho \sigma)-2I_{0}(\rho \sigma)K_{0}(\sigma) $. Some rough approximations from Wolfram Alpha (by letting $R=20$) seem to confirm this.
